# function not defined, but i'm quite sure i defined it.. What am i missing?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to make a form using HTML & JavaScript.
I defined a lot of functions, but one of them is giving me some errors saying the functions aren't defined.. I'm quite sure though that i defined them.. Maybe i miss something somewhere or i defined them incorrectly? Not quite sure where the problem is!

The errors i'm getting are:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedBinding is not defined*

*Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedStaples is not defined*

*Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedHoles is not defined*

Maybe you guys can check my code and look for the error i can't find?

```js
var elems = {
  staplesSelect: document.getElementById("makingStaples"),
  holeSelect: document.getElementById("makingHoles"),
  bindingSelect: document.getElementById("makingBinding"),
  amountOfSetsResults: document.getElementById("amountOfSetsResults"),
  amountOfPagesResults: document.getElementById("amountOfPagesResults"),
  binding: document.getElementById("binding"),
  stapling: document.getElementById("stapling"),
  holes: document.getElementById("holes"),
  paperWeight: document.getElementById("paperWeight"),
  bindingResults: document.getElementById("bindingResults"),
  holesResults: document.getElementById("holesResults"),
  staplingResults: document.getElementById("staplingResults"),
  totalAmountOfPagesResults: document.getElementById("totalAmountOfPagesResults"),
  paperWeightResults: document.getElementById("paperWeightResults"),
  bindingMethod: document.getElementById("bindingMethod"),
  staplingMethod: document.getElementById("staplingMethod"),
  holesMethod: document.getElementById("holesMethod"),
  doubleSided: document.getElementById("doubleSided"),
  pricePaperWeightResults: document.getElementById("pricePaperWeightResults"),
  blackAndWhite: document.getElementById("blackAndWhite"),
  colorResults: document.getElementById("colorResults"),
  totalPricePrints: document.getElementById("totalPricePrints"),
  totalPrice: document.getElementById("totalPrice"),
  pricePerPageResults: document.getElementById("pricePerPageResults"),
  calculation: document.getElementById("calculation"),
  calculate: document.getElementById("calculate"),
  amountOfSetsInput: document.getElementById("amountOfSetsInput"),
  amountOfPagesInput: document.getElementById("amountOfPagesInput")
}

// Hiding calculations from page
toggleVisibility(elems.calculation, true);

// Defining the color prints pricelist
var priceListColor = {
  0: 0.8,
  10: 0.7,
  25: 0.6,
  50: 0.5,
  100: 0.4,
  250: 0.35,
  500: 0.3,
  1000: 0.25,
  2000: 0.2,
  5000: 0.18
}
// Defining the black and white pricelist
var priceListBlackAndWhite = {
  0: 0.1,
  10: 0.09,
  25: 0.08,
  50: 0.07,
  100: 0.06,
  500: 0.05,
  1000: 0.045,
  5000: 0.04
}

// Defining the pricelist for paperweight
var priceListPaperWeight = {
  80: 0,
  120: 0.05,
  160: 0.1,
  190: 0.15,
  210: 0.2,
  250: 0.25,
  280: 0.3,
  300: 0.35,
  350: 0.4,
  351: 0
}

// Defining the pricelist for binding
var priceListBinding = {
  0: 3,
  10: 2.75,
  25: 2.5  
}

// Defining the pricelist for stapling
var priceListStaples = {
  0: 0.15,
  100: 0.12,
  250: 0.10,
  500: 0.08
}

// Defining the pricelist for stapling
var priceListHoles = {
  0: 0.15,
  100: 0.12,
  250: 0.10,
  500: 0.08
}

// Getting the value for the amount of pages given in by user
function finalAmountOfPages() {
  var totalAmountOfSets = elems.amountOfSetsInput.value || 0;
  var totalAmountOfPages = elems.amountOfPagesInput.value || 0;

  // Validation process, returns true or false; if true we proceed
  if (validateForm(totalAmountOfSets, totalAmountOfPages)) {
    totalAmountOfPages = parseInt(totalAmountOfPages);
    totalAmountOfSets = parseInt(totalAmountOfSets);

    // Calculating total amount of pages
    var finalPagesAmount = totalAmountOfPages * totalAmountOfSets;

    // Calculating price per page
    var pricePerColorPage = findPricePerColorPage(finalPagesAmount, 0);
    var pricePerBlackAndWhitePage = findPricePerBlackAndWhitePage(finalPagesAmount, 0);
    var totalPriceColorPrinting = (totalAmountOfPages * totalAmountOfSets) * pricePerColorPage;
    var totalPriceBlackAndWhitePrinting = (totalAmountOfPages * totalAmountOfSets) * pricePerBlackAndWhitePage;

    // Calculating price for binding
    var bindingPrice = findBindingPrice(totalAmountOfSets, 0);
    var totalBindingPrice = totalAmountOfSets * bindingPrice;

    // Calculating price for paper weight
    var paperWeightPricePerPage = findPaperWeightPrice(paperWeight, 0)
    var totalPricePaper = (totalAmountOfSets * totalAmountOfPages) * paperWeightPricePerPage;
    var totalPricePaperDoubleSided = (totalAmountOfSets * (totalAmountOfPages / 2)) * paperWeightPricePerPage;

    // Setting the startup costs
    var startUpCosts = 2.95;

    // Calculation price for stapling and making holes
    var staplePrice = findStaplePrice(totalAmountOfSets, 0);
    var holesPrice = findHolesPrice(totalAmountOfSets, 0);
    var totalStaplePrice = totalAmountOfSets * staplePrice;
    var totalHolesPrice = totalAmountOfSets * holesPrice;

    // Calculating total price
    var totalColorPrice = totalPriceColorPrinting + totalPricePaper + totalBindingPrice + startUpCosts || 0;
    var totalBlackAndWhitePrice = totalPriceBlackAndWhitePrinting + totalPricePaper + totalBindingPrice + startUpCosts || 0;


    // Calling the updateView function
    //COMMENT 8 first see COMMENT 7. Instead of passing a list of parametres, pass an object
    /* updateView({
            totalAmountOfSets : totalAmountOfSets,
            totalAmountOfPages: totalAmountOfPages
     })*/
    updateView({
      totalAmountOfSets: totalAmountOfSets,
      totalAmountOfPages: totalAmountOfPages,
      totalColorPrice: totalColorPrice,
      totalBlackAndWhitePrice: totalBlackAndWhitePrice,
      pricePerColorPage: pricePerColorPage,
      pricePerBlackAndWhitePage: pricePerBlackAndWhitePage,
      paperWeightPricePerPage: paperWeightPricePerPage,
      totalPricePaper: totalPricePaper,
      totalPricePaperDoubleSided: totalPricePaperDoubleSided,
      bindingPrice: bindingPrice,
      totalBindingPrice: totalBindingPrice,
      totalPriceBlackAndWhitePrinting: totalPriceBlackAndWhitePrinting,
      totalPriceColorPrinting: totalPriceColorPrinting,
      startUpCosts: startUpCosts,
      totalHolesPrice: totalHolesPrice,
      totalStaplePrice: totalStaplePrice
    });

    // Calling the function the show the calculation table
    showCalculation();
  }
}


//COMMENT 7 Instead of "geen" it's better to use "0". I understand that you use it as a value for the resulting offerte so let's save this thing for the next iteration. The best practice is to separate the labels from the values and keep values in an "international form", sometimes numeric. So if the user selects option with value 2, you have somewhere an object where you see that number 2 corresponds to "Color black" and then you show the words "Color black" in the offerte. So in the future we'll rewrite it this way.

function toggleVisibility(selector, hide){
  var showStyle  = hide ?  "none" : "";
  selector.style.display = showStyle;
}

// Defining a function to hide 'makingStaples' and 'makingHoles' when binding is different from "geen"
function toggleBinding (){
  if (getValue(selectedBinding) !== "geen") {
    toggleVisibility(elems.staplesSelect, true);
    toggleVisibility(elems.holeSelect, true);
  } else {
    toggleVisibility(elems.staplesSelect, false);
    toggleVisibility(elems.holeSelect, false);
  }  
}

// Defining a function to hide 'makingBinding' and 'makingHoles' when staples is different from "geen"
function toggleStapling (){
  if (getValue(selectedStaples) !== "geen") {
    toggleVisibility(elems.bindingSelect, true);
    toggleVisibility(elems.holeSelect, true);
  } else {
    toggleVisibility(elems.bindingSelect, false);
    toggleVisibility(elems.holeSelect, false);
  }  
}

// Defining a function to hide 'makingStaples' and 'makingBinding' when holes is different from "geen"
function toggleHoles (){
  if (getValue(selectedHoles) !== "geen") {
    toggleVisibility(elems.staplesSelect, true);
    toggleVisibility(elems.bindingSelect, true);
  } else {
    toggleVisibility(elems.staplesSelect, false);
    toggleVisibility(elems.bindingSelect, false);
  }  
}

// Function to show the calculation table after pressing the button
function showCalculation() {
  toggleVisibility(elems.calculation, false);
}

// Defining a function to validate all fields
function validateForm(totalAmountOfSets, totalAmountOfPages) {
  elems.amountOfSetsResults.innerHTML = "";
  elems.amountOfPagesResults.innerHTML = "";
  // Validating the input fields
  if (!totalAmountOfPages || isNaN(totalAmountOfPages) || totalAmountOfPages <= 0) { 
    elems.amountOfPagesResults.innerHTML = "Controleer uw invoer!";
    return false; //validation not passed
  } else if (!totalAmountOfSets || isNaN(totalAmountOfSets) || totalAmountOfSets <= 0) { 
    elems.amountOfSetsResults.innerHTML = "Controleer uw invoer!";
    return false; //validation not passed
  } else {
    return true; //validation passed
  }
}

// Defining a price per page for color prints
function findPricePerColorPage(numberOfPages, initialNumber) {
  pricePerColorPage = initialNumber;
  for (var amount in priceListColor) {
    if (numberOfPages > amount) {
      pricePerColorPage = priceListColor[amount]
    }
  }
  return pricePerColorPage;
}

// Defining a price per page for black and white prints
function findPricePerBlackAndWhitePage(numberOfPages, initialNumber) {
  pricePerBlackAndWhitePage = initialNumber;
  for (var amount in priceListBlackAndWhite) {
    if (numberOfPages > amount) {
      pricePerBlackAndWhitePage = priceListBlackAndWhite[amount]
    }
  }    
  return pricePerBlackAndWhitePage;
}

/* Getting the binding value
function getBinding(selectedBinding) {
  var b = elems.binding;
  var selectedBinding = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedBinding;
} 

// Getting the holes value
function getHoles(selectedHoles) {
  var h = elems.holes;
  var selectedHoles = h.options[h.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedHoles;
}


// Getting the paper weight value
function getPaperWeight(selectedPaperWeight) {
  var pW = elems.paperWeight;
  var selectedPaperWeight = pW.options[pW.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedPaperWeight;
}
*/

// Getting the text from staples, holes, binding and paperweight
function getText(textBinding, textStapling, textHoles, textPaperWeight) {
  var b = elems.binding;
  var s = elems.stapling;
  var h = elems.holes;
  var p = elems.paperWeight;
  var textBinding = b.options[b.selectedIndex].text;
  var textStapling = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
  var textHoles = h.options[h.selectedIndex].text;
  var textPaperWeight = p.options[p.selectedIndex].text;
  return textBinding, textStapling, textHoles, textPaperWeight;
}

// Getting the value from staples, holes, binding and paperweight
function getValue(selectedStapling, selectedBinding, selectedHoles, selectedPaperWeight) {
  var b = elems.binding;
  var s = elems.stapling;
  var h = elems.holes;
  var p = elems.paperWeight;
  var selectedStapling = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedBinding = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedHoles = h.options[h.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedPaperWeight = p.options[p.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedStapling, selectedBinding, selectedHoles, selectedPaperWeight;
}

// Defining the price for binding
function findBindingPrice(totalAmountOfSets, initialNumber) {
  var bindingPrice = initialNumber;
  if (getValue(selectedBinding) === "geen") {
    return bindingPrice = 0;
  } else {
    for (var amount in priceListBinding) {
      if (totalAmountOfSets > amount) {
        bindingPrice = priceListBinding[amount]
      }
    }
  } 
  return bindingPrice;
}

// Defining the price for making staples
function findStaplePrice(totalAmountOfSets, initialNumber) {
  var staplePrice = initialNumber;
  if (getValue(selectedStaples) === "geen") {
    return staplePrice = 0;
  } else {
    for (var amount in priceListStaples) {
      if (totalAmountOfSets > amount) {
        staplePrice = priceListStaples[amount]
      }
    }
  } 
  return staplePrice;
}

//COMMENT 5 this function is almost identical with getStaples(). Let's remove it and modify getStaples is some way to always use it. Maybe we will pass element as the second parameter?


// Defining the price for making holes
function findHolesPrice(totalAmountOfSets, initialNumber) {
  var holesPrice = initialNumber;
  if (getValue(selectedHoles) === "geen") {
    return holesPrice = 0;
  } else {
    for (var amount in priceListHoles) {
      if (totalAmountOfSets > amount) {
        holesPrice = priceListHoles[amount]
      }
    }
  } 
  return holesPrice;
}

//COMMENT 6 this function is almost identical with getStaples(). Let's remove it and modify getStaples is some way to always use it. Maybe we will pass element as the second parameter?


// Defining a paper weight price
function findPaperWeightPrice(paperWeight, initialNumber) {
  paperWeightPricePerPage = initialNumber;
  for (var amount in priceListPaperWeight) {
    if (getValue(selectedPaperWeight) >= amount) {
      paperWeightPricePerPage = priceListPaperWeight[amount]
    }
  }
  return parseFloat(paperWeightPricePerPage);
}

// Defining a function to update the price
function updateView(amount) {
  elems.bindingResults.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.totalBindingPrice.toFixed(2);
  elems.holesResults.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.totalHolesPrice.toFixed(2);
  elems.staplingResults.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.totalStaplePrice.toFixed(2);
  elems.totalAmountOfPagesResults.innerHTML = amount.totalAmountOfSets * amount.totalAmountOfPages;
  elems.paperWeightResults.innerHTML = getText(textPaperWeight) + " gr.";
  elems.bindingMethod.innerHTML = getText(textBinding);
  elems.staplingMethod.innerHTML = getText(textStaples);
  elems.holesMethod.innerHTML = getText(textHoles);
  if (elems.doubleSided.checked) {
    elems.pricePaperWeightResults.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.totalPricePaperDoubleSided.toFixed(2);
  } else {
    elems.pricePaperWeightResults.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.totalPricePaper.toFixed(2);
  }
  // Making the decision to show black and white totalprice and price per page
  if (elems.blackAndWhite.checked) {
    elems.colorResults.innerHTML = "Zwart-Wit"
    elems.totalPricePrints.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.totalPriceBlackAndWhitePrinting.toFixed(2);
    elems.totalPrice.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.totalBlackAndWhitePrice.toFixed(2);
    elems.pricePerPageResults.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.pricePerBlackAndWhitePage.toFixed(2);
  }
  // or to show the color totalprice and price per page
  else {
    elems.colorResults.innerHTML = "Kleur"
    elems.totalPricePrints.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.totalPriceColorPrinting.toFixed(2);
    elems.totalPrice.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.totalColorPrice.toFixed(2);
    elems.pricePerPageResults.innerHTML = "\u20ac " + amount.pricePerColorPage.toFixed(2);
  }
}

// Defining an Event Listener with an on click function
elems.calculate.addEventListener("click", finalAmountOfPages);

// Defining the Event Listeners to hide or show 'makingHoles', 'makingStaples' and 'binding'
elems.stapling.addEventListener("change", toggleStapling);
elems.binding.addEventListener("change", toggleBinding);
elems.holes.addEventListener("change", toggleHoles);
```

```html
<h1>Bereken de kosten</h1>
<table>
  <!-- Ask the user to enter the amount of pages -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Aantal pagina's:</p></td>
    <td><p><input type="number" id="amountOfPagesInput"></p></td>
    <td><p id="amountOfPagesResults"></p></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Ask the user to enter the amount of sets -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Aantal sets:</p></td>
    <td><p><input type="number" id="amountOfSetsInput"></p></td>
    <td><p id="amountOfSetsResults"></p></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Ask user for color of the print / standard selected is color -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Kleur van afdruk: </p></td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" value="kleur" name="pickYourColor" id="color" checked="true"> Kleur
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="zwart-wit" name="pickYourColor" id="blackAndWhite"> Zwart-Wit
      </p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Ask the user if he wants single or double sided prints / standard selected is single sided -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Enkel of dubbelzijdig: </p></td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" value="enkelzijdig" name="singleOrDoubleSided" id="singleSided" checked="true"> Enkelzijdig
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="dubbelzijdig" name="singleOrDoubleSided" id="doubleSided"> Dubbelzijdig
      </p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Ask the user which paperweight he wants -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Papierdikte: </p></td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <select id="paperWeight">
          <option value="80" id="80gr">Standaard papier</option>
          <option value="120" id="120gr">120 grams + &euro; 0,05</option>
          <option value="160" id="160gr">160 grams + &euro; 0,10</option>
          <option value="190" id="190gr">190 grams + &euro; 0,15</option>
          <option value="210" id="210gr">210 grams + &euro; 0,20</option>
          <option value="250" id="250gr">250 grams + &euro; 0,25</option>
          <option value="280" id="280gr">280 grams + &euro; 0,30</option>
          <option value="300" id="300gr">300 grams + &euro; 0,35</option>
          <option value="350" id="350gr">350 grams + &euro; 0,40</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Specifing the binding -->
  <tr id="makingBinding">
    <td><p>Inbinden: </p></td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <select id="binding">
          <option value="geen" id="none">-- Niet inbinden --</option>
          <option value="wire-o" id="wire-o">Wire-O ringband</option>
          <option value="thermo" id="thermo">Thermo lijmstrip</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="makingStaples">
    <td><p>Nieten: </p></td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <select id="stapling">
          <option value="geen" id="none">-- Niet nieten --</option>
          <option value="1" id="1left">1 nietje links</option>
          <option value="2" id="1right">1 nietje rechts</option>
          <option value="3" id="1left">2 nietjes links</option>
          <option value="4" id="foldAndStaple">vouwen + nieten</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="makingHoles">
    <td><p>Perforeren: </p></td>
    <td>
      <p>
        <select id="holes">
          <option value="geen" id="none">-- Niet perforeren --</option>
          <option value="2 gaten" id="2holes">2 gaten</option>
          <option value="4 gaten" id="4holes">4 gaten</option>
        </select>
      <p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Berekenen">
<hr/>
<!-- Start calculation -->
<table id="calculation">
  <tr>
    <td><h2>Uw Offerte:</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Show the amount of pages -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Totaal aantal pagina's:</p></td>
    <td><p id="totalAmountOfPagesResults"></p></td>
    <!-- Show the total price -->
    <td><p>Prijs per zijde:</p> </td>
    <td><p id="pricePerPageResults"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Kleur of Zwart-wit:</p></td>
    <td><p id="colorResults"></p></td>
    <td><p>Totaal voor printen: </p></td>
    <td><p id="totalPricePrints"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Show the price for paper weight -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Papierdikte: </p></td>
    <td><p id="paperWeightResults"></p></td>
    <!-- Show the total price -->
    <td><p>Totaal voor papier: </p></td>
    <td><p id="pricePaperWeightResults"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Show the chosen binding method -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Inbindmethode: </p></td>
    <td><p id="bindingMethod"></p></td>
    <!-- Show the total price -->
    <td><p>Totaal voor inbinden: </p></td>
    <td><p id="bindingResults"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Show the chosen stapling method -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Nietjes: </p></td>
    <td><p id="staplingMethod"></p></td>
    <!-- Show the total price -->
    <td><p>Totaal voor nieten: </p></td>
    <td><p id="staplingResults"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Show the chosen binding method -->
  <tr>
    <td><p>Perforatie: </p></td>
    <td><p id="holesMethod"></p></td>
    <!-- Show the total price -->
    <td><p>Totaal voor perforeren: </p></td>
    <td><p id="holesResults"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Show startup costs -->
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>Opstartkosten: </p></td>
    <td><p>€ 2,95</p></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Show the price per page -->
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3>Totaalprijs: </h3></td>
    <td><h3 id="totalPrice"></h3></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where is the declaration of variable selectedStaples  ?

Comment: What is that getValue function even doing? It accepts 4 arguments but you are always filling in only one and outputing again 4 and comparing them with string?

Comment: Here is defined the function:
`function getValue(selectedStapling, selectedBinding, selectedHoles, selectedPaperWeight) {
  var b = elems.binding;
  var s = elems.stapling;
  var h = elems.holes;
  var p = elems.paperWeight;
  var selectedStapling = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedBinding = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedHoles = h.options[h.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedPaperWeight = p.options[p.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedStapling, selectedBinding, selectedHoles, selectedPaperWeight;
}
`
It is supposed to take the values

Comment: and pass this info to later in the script; the function findStaplePrice() for example, there im trying to get the value from the staple select option and to give it a price due to the value. I used to have four functions doing this job, which are still there but commented out, but i wanted to make it a bit more readable and reuseable, which turned out to be a problem XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedBinding is not defined.

```
// Defining a function to hide 'makingStaples' and 'makingHoles' when binding is different from "geen"
function toggleBinding (){
    if (getValue(selectedBinding) !== "geen") {
    toggleVisibility(elems.staplesSelect, true);
    toggleVisibility(elems.holeSelect, true);
  } else {
    toggleVisibility(elems.staplesSelect, false);
    toggleVisibility(elems.holeSelect, false);
  }  
}
```

This function uses `selectedBinding` but this is not defined before this function is called. Declare a variable `selectedBinding` before using it.

Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedStaples is not defined

```
// Defining a function to hide 'makingBinding' and 'makingHoles' when staples is different from "geen"
function toggleStapling (){
    if (getValue(selectedStaples) !== "geen") {
        toggleVisibility(elems.bindingSelect, true);
    toggleVisibility(elems.holeSelect, true);
  } else {
        toggleVisibility(elems.bindingSelect, false);
    toggleVisibility(elems.holeSelect, false);
  }  
}
```

Again the same issue here. There is no declaration of selectedStaples.

Similar issue is with selectedHoles.

I see in your code you are actually making a declaration in the commented code of yours:

```
/* Getting the binding value
function getBinding(selectedBinding) {
  var b = elems.binding;
  var selectedBinding = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedBinding;
}
```

When you declare a variable inside a function, you are limiting its scope to the function. Which means that this will not be available outside the function. Your need to declare these variables so that they are available to functions like toggleBinding etc and it will fix your current issue.

Comment: I tried to declare it instead of the commented code you showed, here:
`function getValue(selectedStapling, selectedBinding, selectedHoles, selectedPaperWeight) {
  var b = elems.binding;
  var s = elems.stapling;
  var h = elems.holes;
  var p = elems.paperWeight;
  var selectedStapling = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedBinding = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedHoles = h.options[h.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedPaperWeight = p.options[p.selectedIndex].value;
  return selectedStapling, selectedBinding, selectedHoles, selectedPaperWeight;
}`

Comment: These variables are available inside getValue function and not the entire global scope. I am not sure if returning like the way you did is the right way. Try to write one function at a time, and when it works move on to next, else you will end up with a huge js code and no good way to debug it.